# How can I get data in the required field?

Tags: oracle, report

`C.PREF_FIRST_NAME` (preferred first name)
`C.PATNER_LAST_NAME` (partner last name)  from table

```
per_person_names_f
```

I have tried with KNOWN_AS(preferred last name field which is present in the table but data is empty.

How can I add these two columns to report in Oracle HCM cloud?

Comment: Sample data and expected output will help us resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use preferred first name and default to partner last name, then:

```
NVL(C.PREF_FIRST_NAME, NVL(C.PATNER_LAST_NAME, ''))
```

If you want to have both, then:

```
NVL(C.PREF_FIRST_NAME, '') || ' ' || NVL(C.PATNER_LAST_NAME, '')
```

EDIT

I have seen your comment that you have accidentally posted as an edit to this answer, so, you have tried

```
NVL(ppnf.known_as Preferred_First_Name, NVL(ppnf.Previous_Last_name Patner_Last_name, ''))
```

but got a legal identifier error. The `as` keyword is renaming a field in the selection. The selection starts with the `select` keyword and this clause consists of comma-separated fields, like

```
select f1, f2, f3, f4
...
```

You can rename a field like this:

```
select f1, f2, f3 as fancyfield, f4
...
```

however, you can only rename a field. If you have

```
select f1, f2, nvl(somevalue, nvl(someothervalue, '')), f4
...
```

then `nvl(somevalue, nvl(someothervalue, ''))` is a field and you can rename it like

```
select f1, f2, nvl(somevalue, nvl(someothervalue, '')) as fancyfield, f4
...
```

but you cannot rename a parameter of a function as a field, like `nvl(somevalue as fancyfield, nvl(someothervalue as anotherfancyfield, ''))`, because renaming a field has the purpose of ensuring that the field names of your result set, or, the resulting relation, if you will has the field names you prefer. However, the parameter you pass to a function will not be a field in the result set due to being a parameter that you use as raw material to compute a field. From your try it seems that you want to get what value you need while knowing what it was. If so, then you can achieve it like this:

```
NVL(ppnf.known_as, '') as Preferred_First_Name, NVL(ppnf.Previous_Last_name, '') as Patner_Last_name, NVL(ppnf.known_as, NVL(ppnf.Previous_Last_name, '')) as Name
```

Comment: @marc_s thank you for the edit, but patner (instead of partner) was intentional, to comply to the fields used by the asker. Preffered (instead of preferred) was done with the same reason. Hence, your edit, even though it made some grammatical fixes, I think did not improve the question, nor the answer, because I think the naming used by the asker is to be preferred. A beginner is confused by the problem already and will not necessarily understand a solution where the fields are named in a grammatically correct manner, but differing from the fields he has.

Answer (score 0):

In names table (per_person_names_f) we have two name types( NAME_TYPE ) **global and local**.

Usually users update their formal name in global name type and preferred name in local name type.

So try to use the name type in your sql to get the values.

Note: The local name type will be optional most cases. So it may not be there for some of the person records.

If you are looking for a preferred name type that holds first name and last name like PeopleSoft.. it may not be there in HCM. The nearest equivalent field is KNOWN_AS which is also option field usually.